# My Rewarded Ad is buggy and doesn't behave correctly ( Android Studio )

Tags: android, kotlin, ads

*Hey there~*

i'm new to android development and have been trying to implement a rewarded ad for the first time in android studio.

**issue: when i click on the button, the ad is supposed to show, and once it finishes showing, "CP" variable should be incremented by 1. instead, the button sometimes doesn't work (opening the ad after the second or third press only) and the variable doesn't get incremented.**

I have zero experience in kotlin and have been copying and pasting stuff up to this point. been trying to fix this issue for two days.
here's my code:

```
package [REDACTED]
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*
import com.google.android.gms.ads.rewarded.RewardItem
import com.google.android.gms.ads.rewarded.RewardedAd
import com.google.android.gms.ads.rewarded.RewardedAdLoadCallback
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_contracts.*

class ContractsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_contracts) {

    private var mRewardedAd : RewardedAd? = null
    private var TAG = "ContractsFragment"
    private var CP = 0
    var progressBarRewardedProgress = CP * 10

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        lateinit var mAdView : AdView
        lateinit var mAdView2 : AdView

        loadData()
        progressBarRewarded.max = 50
        ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBarRewarded, "progress", progressBarRewardedProgress)
            .setDuration(1000)
            .start()


        val adRequestRewarded = AdRequest.Builder().build()


        val reward_button = requireView().findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonRewarded)


        MobileAds.initialize(activity) {}

        reward_button.setOnClickListener{
            RewardedAd.load(activity, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", adRequestRewarded, object :
                RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, adError?.message)
                    mRewardedAd = null
                }

                override fun onAdLoaded(rewardedAd: RewardedAd) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ad was loaded.")
                    mRewardedAd = rewardedAd
                }
            })
            mRewardedAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object : FullScreenContentCallback() {
                override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ad was shown.")
                }

                override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ad failed to show.")
                }

                override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    // Called when ad is dismissed.
                    // Set the ad reference to null so you don't show the ad a second time.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ad was dismissed.")
                    mRewardedAd = null
                }
            }

            if (mRewardedAd != null) {
                mRewardedAd?.show(activity, OnUserEarnedRewardListener() {
                    fun onUserEarnedReward(rewardItem: RewardItem) {
                        CP += 1
                        progressBarRewardedProgress = CP * 10
                        saveData()
                        ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBarRewarded, "progress", progressBarRewardedProgress)
                            .setDuration(1000)
                            .start()
                    }
                })
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "The rewarded ad wasn't ready yet.")
            }
        }

        mAdView = requireView().findViewById(R.id.adBanner1)
        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)

        mAdView2 = requireView().findViewById(R.id.adBanner2)
        val adRequest2 = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        mAdView2.loadAd(adRequest2)

    }
    fun saveData() {
        val sharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.apply{
            putInt("CP", CP)
        }.apply()
        Toast.makeText(requireActivity(),"Data saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    fun loadData() {
        val sharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        CP = sharedPreferences.getInt("CP", 0)
        progressBarRewardedProgress = CP * 10
    }
}
```

i'm using android studio arctic fox (latest version)
and all my dependencies are according to the documentation (they work fine for my banner ads)

thanks alot

Comment: On your button click, you are `loading` your Ad which will obviously take time to load. What you can do is load your Ad early (independent of button click) & use `mRewardedAd?.show(...)` on your button click if `mRewardedAd != null`.

Comment: @DarShan i tried that. but i want the button to reset (user can get as many rewards as they want) and this method just renders the button useless after the first time

Comment: you can load the `Ad` again in the `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent` or the `onUserEarnedReward` callback, I'd suggest creating a separate method to load ad.